# Three forms on the same page produce error alert when just one is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise. At the `/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` file I did some changes. I added two other forms. In summary the forms (and the whole file) are like that:

```
   <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
     ...
   <% end %>

    <%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => emailnotifs_path, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f1| %>
     <%= f1.error_notification %>
    ...
    <% end %>

    <%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => updatebilling_path, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f2| %>
      <%= f2.error_notification %>
      ...
    <% end %>
```

If I submit any one of the three forms and an error occurs, all forms show the following error on their `.error_notification`: `Please review the problems below:`

I was wondering why this happens and if is logical. Of course I don't want this to be happening. Each form should be independent. If you need any other information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last two forms, at least, you create a form using the same user instance : @user. When f1 and f2 are created they will both display the same error notification coming from user.

As you are using different action, you could create multiple users in your controller :

```
 @user=User.find(params[id])
 @user_email=User.find(params[id])
 @user_error_notification=User.find(params[id])
```

You can put that in a private controller method that you will call before your update methods, where you will update the correct user. By doing that, the error will only populate one user instance and the others will not display the error.

EDIT: As this is for devise, I do not remember how the first form works exactly, you should check if you need to instantiate @user or if something is done as I guess you are overriding a Devise action.

Answer (score 1):

This is logical and expected behavior due to the fact that the errors are stored on the `@user` object itself and not related to the specific form that was submitted.

Since the errors are stored in the object, if you want the errors to only show next to the submitted form, you will need a separate object for each.